# Split Numbers From Strings Using Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex, string, arraylist

I want to split the numbers from the letters in `masterArray` and store them in separate `ArrayList`s (`splitInteger`, `splitString`). Currently, I have the numbers in `splitInteger` `ArrayList`, but the letters in the `splitString` `ArrayList` is not separating correctly.

`splitString` `ArrayList` has extra spaces, commas, and the order of the elements in the `ArrayList` are not correct.

The output should be the following:

```
[55CC, 1C, 255D, 0F]
[55, 1, 255, 0]
[CC, C, D, F]
```

Currently, the output is as follows:

```
[55CC, 1C, 255D, 0F]
[55, 1, 255, 0]
[, CC, , C, , D, , F]
```

I tried messing with the regular expression for my removeNumbers variable, but don't know much about regular expressions.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SplitArrayExample {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int convertValue = 0;

    // Using Regular Expressions to remove Characters 
    String removeLetters = "([A-z]+)";
    String removeNumbers = "([0-9]+)";

    // This is the master list.
    ArrayList<String> masterArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        masterArray.add("55CC");
        masterArray.add("1C");
        masterArray.add("255D");
        masterArray.add("0F");

    // These are used to split the integer and string characters
    ArrayList<Integer> splitInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> splitString = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String element : masterArray)
    {
        // Used to split the strings
        String[] removingLetterCharacters = element.split(removeLetters);
        String[] removingNumberCharacters = element.split(removeNumbers);

        // This for-each loop removes letter values and converts numbers to integer values
        for(String addObject : removingLetterCharacters)
        {
            convertValue = Integer.parseInt(addObject);
            splitInteger.add(convertValue); 
        }

        // This for-each loop removes the integer values
        for(String addObject : removingNumberCharacters)
        {
            splitString.add(addObject);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(masterArray);
    System.out.println(splitInteger);


    System.out.println(splitString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `split` is used to get the list of letters, the list will contain two elements for each element in the original list: one *empty string*, and the actual string.

For example, for the element `55CC`, the list of letters would contain `[, CC]`.

To solve this, one way is to check if the string is empty prior to adding it in the output list:

```
for (String addObject : removingLetterCharacters) {
    if(!addObject.isEmpty()) {
        convertValue = Integer.parseInt(addObject);
        splitInteger.add(convertValue);
    }
}

for (String addObject : removingNumberCharacters) {
    if(!addObject.isEmpty()) {
        splitString.add(addObject);
    }
}
```

However, using `split` will not work if the original list had more complex combinations of letters and numbers. For example, if the list was `[55CC7, 1C, 255D, 0F]`, then the list of numbers would contain *5* numbers instead of 4 because the `split` method would split the element `55CC7` into two numbers `55` and `7`. A better alternative is to use `String#replaceAll` to replace the pattern with empty strings. In this case, the regex could be simpler:

```
// Using Regular Expressions to remove Characters
String removeLetters = "[A-z]";
String removeNumbers = "\\d";

// This is the master list.
ArrayList<String> masterArray = new ArrayList<String>();
masterArray.add("7CC55");
masterArray.add("1C");
masterArray.add("255D");
masterArray.add("0F");


// These are used to split the integer and string characters
ArrayList<Integer> splitInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<String> splitString = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String element : masterArray) {
   String removingLetterCharacters = element.replaceAll(removeLetters, "");
   String removingNumberCharacters = element.replaceAll(removeNumbers, "");
   splitInteger.add(Integer.parseInt(removingLetterCharacters));
   splitString.add(removingNumberCharacters);
}
```

Comment: @YoungandFree Check my updated answer. `split` may not work for more complex combinations of numbers and letters.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method of String so it removes all the characters or numbers from your String like:

```
String removeLetters = "([A-Z]+)";//you have typo here note capital Z
for (String element : masterArray) {
    String removingLetterCharacters = element.replaceAll(removeLetters, "");
    String removingNumberCharacters = element.replaceAll(removeNumbers, "");
    convertValue = Integer.parseInt(removingLetterCharacters);
    splitInteger.add(convertValue);
    splitString.add(removingNumberCharacters);
}

Output:
[55CC, 1C, 255D, 0F]
[55, 1, 255, 0]
[CC, C, D, F]
```